# Postman Error : Client Network Socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: postman

I am getting this error, any idea what is causing it? I read somewhere in the forum to change https to http or disconnect from VPN. I tried both, it is still failing.

However, the same collection and environment setup is working fine in my colleagues laptop.

Also, my other collection with different environment works fine.

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Answer (score 4):

Socket error usually comes when you have proxy issues :
[image]

see if your proxy settings are correct

Comment: my proxy setting is good, it is same as your screenshot. any other setting i should be checking at?

Comment: try selecting use the system proxy , if your your organization uses proxy to connect to network

Comment: I checked "Use the system proxy" box under Setting. it still gives me same error. I tried off/on vpn, same result. any other setting I should be check?

Comment: without knowing the issue in person its hard to help more than that , see if the https_proxy and http_proxy variable values are same across yours and your colleagues pc . Also check the network through which postman is sending the request, goto console> network>local  and see the ip . Check whether its the same for you and your colleague for the same vpn

Comment: the local IP shows the subnet through which postman access the target ,

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem.
In my case I add client certificate in Settings->Certificates->Client Certificates

Answer (score 0):

I had same error - in my case the proxy configuration was not supporting HTTPS. So you might just use proxy type HTTP